# fancybox variables

Tags: php, jquery, forms, variables, fancybox

Okay, So I have a question about passing variables. What I want to do is pass some variables from a form to a fancybox that is loading a php page that confirms the form data, etc.

```
<form action="bvd-email-opt-in.php" method="post">
<div style="width:125px; float:left;">
    <label style="font-size:12px" for="first_name">First Name:</label>
    <input style="width:110px" name="first_name" id="first_name" required="required" type="text">
</div>
<div style="width:125px; float:right;">
    <label style="font-size:12px" for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
    <input style="width:110px" name="last_name" id="last_name" required="required" type="text">
</div>
<div class="cle"></div>
<div id="email-container" style="width:180px; height:20px; float:left">
    <label style="font-size:12px; line-height:13px;" for="email">Email Address:</label>
    <br />
    <input style="width:175px;" name="email" id="email" required="required" type="text">
</div>
<div id="form-submit" style="float:right; padding-top:18px;">
    <input name="submit" type="button" value="Go" style="float:right;margin-right:12px" id="go" />
</div>
<div class="cle"></div>
```

And here is the way the function is set up currently:

```
$("#go").bind("click", function () {

  $.fancybox({

    'content': '<div id="commentForm"><h1>Join Our Email List</h1><iframe src="bvd-email-opt-in.php" width="500" frameborder="0" height="480"></iframe></div>'

  });

});
```

Now I know that the way it's loading right now, the data is not being passed to the form. What I don't know is what the best method may be to do so.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the values you need inside your click function, and pass them as a GET request. For example :

```
$("#go").bind("click", function () {
   var mail = $('#email').value();
$.fancybox({

'content': '<div id="commentForm"><h1>Join Our Email List</h1><iframe src="bvd-email-opt-in.php?mail='+mail+'" width="500" frameborder="0" height="480"></iframe></div>'

 });

});
```

Comment: Attempting the function in this way caused the iframe to not load. Not sure why... seems logical and was kind of on the same path as I was.

Comment: What happens when you open bvd-email-opt-in.php?email="whatever@host.com" in your browser?

Comment: I fixed it. I used getelementbyid and .value to obtain the values from the form fields and pass them to the php in URL fashion for a GET on the other side. When I used your formatting, it worked. Just have to know that when the Javascript action is placed on the button, it no longer "submits" in the traditional way. Works!

Comment: Good. If you could please mark my answer as OK :)

Also, if you add a return true; to your binding function, the form will be submitted.